# 301 htaccess redirect of frontpage only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Edited: To better explain what i want.

We want to move our frontpage `http://www.example.com`, to a subpage `http://www.example.com/sub-page`.

So in order to keep our SEO ranking we need to write a 301 permanently moved. And we would like the sub-page URL to be displayed in the browser.
This should be displayed `http://www.example.com/sub-page/`

So the result will be if you try to enter `http://www.example.com`, your url will be rewritten to `http://www.example.com/sub-page/` with a 301 redirect.

But every other page should not be redirected!
E.g. `http://www.example.com/contact/` should still be the same.

And it should also take care of every variations of the root-domain.
With and without trailing slashes (`example.com`/ vs `example.com`)
With and without www (`www.example.com` vs `example.com`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> 1. Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess. 
> 2. Create and deploy your new home page as `/sub-page`
> 3. Then put this code in your .htaccess file under DOCUMENT_ROOT:
> ```

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# reqest to example.com/ will be forwarded to example.com/sub-page
RewriteRule ^$ sub-page [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am a bit confused with your solution. Will users trying to access `example.com/sub-page/` be redirected to the root-domain? Why would i want this? I want the opposite. The second section with the forward from root to sub-page: Will this show the url as `example.com/sub-page`? And will it show a 301 permanently moved?

Comment: As per the 2nd rule URL in browser will remain `example.com` but content will be served from `example.com/sub-page`. Now the whole point about being sensitive to SEO is to not to serve exact same content from 2 URIs. Now if you don't have 1st rule then `example.com/` and `example.com/sub-page` will serve same content that you must avoid. Hence my 1st rule will externally redirect (change URL in browser) from `example.com/sub-page` to `example.com/` hence no matter what browser URL will always be `example.com/` and search engines will not punish you for this.

Comment: Also remember to change from `R` to `R=301` in Rule # 1, once you are sure everything is working.

Comment: Thanks for your update. What i actually want is the opposite of what you are describing. I want the url to be `example.com/sub-page` and i want `example.com` to be rewritten to `example.com/sub-page` And thats why i want a 301 on the root domain. To prevent duplicate content.

Comment: Oh ok alright I understand what you want. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

.htacces

```
^/|/index.html|/index.php$     /sub-page
```

add your font page as you like.
^ represent line head.
$ represent line end.

Comment: We do not use index.html or index.php. But will the ^/ /sub-page redirect http://www.example.com and http://www.example.com/ to /sub-page. And leave every other url as they are? E.g. http://www.example.com/abc should not be redirected at all.